# Environment variable with period in using supervisor started node process

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, environment-variables, supervisord

I have a node process that uses an environment variable in the form `SECRET_KEY=1234.5678.910112`.

This works fine if set using export in my bash_profile and the process is run directly in the shell.

But when running it using supervisor the script only picks up the part before the first period. This is the case either when reading env vars set in bash_profile or set using environment= in the conf file.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out all I needed to do was to add single quotes around my variable. I did do this before but didn't run `supervisorctl reread` to get the new config.